# Running Galleria jquery plugin on cakephp

Tags: jquery-plugins, galleria

I tried "Galleria" as a standalone application and it works perfectly fine ..  however in order to make it work with Cakephp what are the changes that i need to make ?

I have tried changing the path of js and css files to absolute path .. it didnt help ..

// Load the classic theme
Galleria.loadTheme('http://localhost/agm2/js/galleria.classic.js');

and in galleria.classic.js .. changed the following line
css: 'http://localhost/agm2/css/galleria.classic.css',

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did before it finally worked and I of course violated cakephp convensions:

I put all the javascript files (jquery, galleria, galleria.classic) in the cakephp js folder. Additionally, I had to put the images (classic-map.png, classic-loader) and the css file (galleria.classic.css) in the cakephp *js* folder before it finally worked.

But under normal circumstances, the galleria css file should be in the css folder, the images in the img folder and the galleria.classic.js should be able to locate them and this is the problem we have.